# Can we say "park moved" instead of using the passive voice?

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice

How do I say the car park is moved?
Is either example grammatical?

"Car park area moved to …"  or

"Car park area was moved to …"

Comment: For a start, they're not questions so they don't need question marks. Are you making a statement or wondering what to put on a sign at an entrance?

Comment: If you want to give the information that the car park (or "parking") is in a different location, then say **Parking has been moved to...** or **Free Parking is in [name of street]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary if you don't know who moved the car park.

You'd ask:

-Where was the car park area moved to?

If you wanted it to be active voice, you could use an anonymous "they":

-Where'd they move the car park area to?

By the by, the term "car park" is British English, so I can't say for sure, but saying "car park area" sounds like it may be redundant, like you should either just say "car park" or say "parking area" instead.

Comment: Thank you very much @Billy H. So "Car park moved to" statement is grammatically not true?

Comment: "Car park moved to" does not make any sense. A statement would be something like "The car park has been moved to the other side of the street" (or wherever it now is).

Comment: @maibrick If it’s on a sign (which might use telegram-style grammar), “Car park moved to [new location]” would be fine. You wouldn’t say it in conversation or write it in normal writing; only where the headline/telegram style would be likely to be used.